# Error Terms in the ANOVA Summary Table

Tags: mathematical-statistics, anova, error, psychology

my lecturers require us to write the error term for the effect/source in the ANOVA summary table. Such as below:

[image: ANOVA summary table example.]

I don't understand how to find which S(error) term goes to which source. And I do know it depends every time, whether the term is within- or between-subjects because the between-Ss factors go in the brackets () when it's a repeated measure/within-Subjects design. Can someone explain it to me like I'm 5. I work best with rules, this is so basic and important but I just can't wrap my head around it! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Expected values of the MSs, in terms of the parameters of the ANOVA model, can point the way to which MS is used for the denominator of each F-statistic (that's the 'Error Term' in your output). // EMSs can depend on which terms in the model are nested and which are random effects (as opposed to fixed effects). There are algorithms for finding EMSs, unfortunately with some controversy which algorithm to use. Some statistical software programs show EMSs.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer based on my Comment:

For example, in your output. The 'Error Term' of the F-ratio for testing effect A is $\mathrm{AS(BC)},$ so the F-ratio is $\mathrm{MS(A)} = 693\,600$ divided by $\mathrm{MS(AS(BC))} =2098.5,$ giving $\mathrm{F(A)} = 693\,600/2098.5 = 330.5.$

The degrees of freedom for this F-statistic
are 1 and 8, so the P-value for effect A is nearly $0$ and the effect is highly significant. Also, the 5% critical value for this test is $5.32,$ as noted in your table; effect A is significant at the 5% level because $330.5 > 5.32.$ (Computations below, using R.)

```
1 - pf(330.5, 1, 8) 
[1] 8.61253e-08
qf(.95, 1, 8)
[1] 5.317655
```

Your software uses EMSs to determine the 'error term'.